# Firebase Authentication In Facebook Browser Not Working

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code to log in a user with a Google Account.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
}).catch(function(error) {
});
```

When the login is complete, it fires the following code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(me) {
    if (me) {
        //user logged in
    }
});
```

In Chrome, Firefox, the PWA, and other browsers fire the event listener to let the user login. The Facebook Inline Browser is the only one that doesn't proceed with the sign-in process. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my bug. I was checking for notification permissions on an iOS device without push notification support, generating an error. The workaround was to disable push notifications on iOS devices and alert the user.